# ajax запрос по ссылке

Tags: php, ajax

В интернете нахожу реализацию ajax запросов только с формами, может плохо ищу. 
Мне нужно, что бы я в index.php кликнул по ссылке, ссылка ведет на обработчик, в котором заносятся данные в бд. И эти данные загрузились в index.php без перезагрузки страницы. 
Как это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index.php

```
<a href='#' id='test'> SendData </a>
```

js (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#test').on('click', function(e){

  $.ajax({
    url: "Обработчик.php",
    datatype: "json",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    method: "POST",
    data: { // ... данные которые отправляем на сервер (например id нажатой ссылки)
       'id':$(this).attr('id')
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
       //... тут ответ с данными от сервера(например результат select from BD), делаем с ними что захотим

    } 
 });  

});
```

Обработчик.php(ловим данные по ключу 'id'):

```
<?php

   $link = $_POST['id'];
   // тут с БД работаем
   // ...
   // возвращаем данные js скрипту (в "success")
   echo json_encode(массив с данными);
?>
```