# ajax запрос по нажатию checkbox

Tags: php, ajax

Доброго времени суток.

Нужен скрипт на jquery ajax, где "при нажатии на input checkbox передается id чекбокса в файл 'likes.php' в формате ассоц массива post в виде id => id чекбокса"

Сам checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="like-1" name="like_status">
<label for="like-1" id="var"><?php echo $arraySumLike1['SUM(likes)']?>
</label>
```

Скрипт пробовал написать сам/переделать из примеров - результат один(не передаются данные в php файл,хотя success у ajax срабатывает).

Comment: посмотрите, может вам поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864710/212496

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "change", function(){
        var elem = $( this ),
            id = elem.attr( "id" );

        if( elem.is( ":checked" ) ){

        $.ajax({
            url: "likes.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function( data )
            {
                console.log( data );
            }
        });

        }

} );
```

Comment: не приходят данные в файл likes.php

Comment: как проверяю:в файле likes.php код <?php var_dump($_POST);?>

Comment: в файле со скриптом запрашиваю файл likes.php  ,

Comment: результат : array(0) { }

Comment: @more7ti в браузере открываете панель разработчика, вкладка Network на нее нажмите. Потом нажмите на чекбокс. Увидите что отправится запрос на файл likes.php на нее нажмете и посмотрите ответ. Код работает, проверил.

Comment: вижу, что отправляет.вопрос только почему в массиве данных не видно?

Comment: ну когда вы открываете просто likes.php, то, вы открываете без передачи доп данных. А когда ajax отправляете, тогда только передаются данные, грубо говоря так. Лучше почитайте ajax, post, get запросы.

Comment: в файле likes.php есть код который не исполняется при отправлении ajax запроса.вот в чем проблема

Comment: судя по консоли, данные все-таки приходят, но алгоритмы все равно не срабатывают,странно

Comment: @Mikhailz это уже иная проблема и вопрос по вашему файлу likes.php