# ajax запрос из php

Tags: php, ajax

доброе утро.
Проблема: на странице (главной) имеется много блоков, в которые нужно загружать список пользователей через цикл php, соответственно, загружается страница очень долго, так как ждет пока загрузятся все блоки и выполнятся все циклы.
Решил сделать это с помощью ajax, но так как полный ноль в нем, не могу разобраться до конца как это работает.
Нужно что бы при наведении на определенный id элемента выполнялся php скрипт (есть отдельный файл).
Когда подключаю файл через include - выполняются все циклы, подключал библиотеку jquery, результата ноль. Файл подгружается сразу при загрузке страницы.
Можете подсказать от чего отталкиваться, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: $('#container').mouseenter(function(){ 
.. code ...
});

Как вариант что-то вроде такого?

Comment: Посмотрите тут (только событие у вас будет mouseenter): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864710/212496

Comment: Вместо `include` необходимо делать AJAX-запросы к PHP, который будет выполнять код из `include` по этому AJAX-запросу. Подключение PHP-кода в JavaScript через `include` не будет делать асинхронных операций, будут выполнены сначала все PHP операции, затем полученный контент будет отправлен в браузер, и только затем будет выполняться JavaScript-код.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#test").mouseenter(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"test.php",
            success:function(){
                alert("success");
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
    },5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='test'>LINK</a>
```

Пример использования. 
setTimeout можно убрать или лучше сократить.

Answer (score 0):

ajax

```js
    <script>
    function load(){
    $.ajax({
url:"https://10.128.100.59/local/templates/.default/components/bitrix/socialnetwork.blog.post/.default/readnotlist.php",
    datatype: "json",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    method: "POST",
       data: { },
                success:function(){
                $("#not-read-<?=$arResult['Post']['ID']?>").html(result.html);
            },
            datatype: "json"
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

php

```html
    <?php
function getBlock(){ 
 foreach (GetNotReadUsers($arResult['Post']['ID']) as $readnot) {
             $rs = CUser::GetByID($readnot);
    $ar = $rs->Fetch();
if ($ar['ACTIVE']=="Y") {
    $avatar=CFile::GetPath($ar['PERSONAL_PHOTO']);
 return ['html' => $ar['LAST_NAME']];
 //echo $ar['LAST_NAME'].'-'.$ar['NAME'].'<br>';
}}}
?>
```

Ответа нет.

Comment: Никогда не смешивайте html, php, js вместе, в одну кучу

Answer (score 0):

**Во-первых**, если долго грузится страница сначала советую проверить ваши запросы...скорее всего их нужно оптимизировать и возможно этого даже будет достаточно...

**Во-вторых**, по наведению лучше ничего не делать, а сделать следующим образом

1.Во все блоки которые нужно "догрузить" добавляем класс "onLoad" и обязательно уникальный id

```
<div id="peoples" class="onLoad"></div>
```

2.Написать php обработчик который будет отдавать html для блоков

```
<?php 
   function getBlock(){ 
      $html = '';
      if(!empty($_POST['block'])){
         $blockId = $_POST['block'];
         //формируем html(подтягиваем наш "view")
         $html = '...';
      }
      return ['html' => $html];
   } 
?>
```

3.Написать метод "инициализации" страницы который будет выглядеть примерно следующим образом

```
<script>
   function load(){
     //запрашиваем данные для необходимых блоков в цыкле
     $(".onLoad").each(function( index ) {
        $id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "url-обработчика",
           data: {block:$id},//post передаем id Блока
           success: function(result){
              //выводим данные в необходимые блоки
              $($id).html(result.html);
           },
           datatype: "json"
        });
     }
   }
</script>
```

4.Вызываем наш "инициализатор" сразу после загрузки страницы

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ load(); }) 
</script>
```

В блоки которые будут добавляться данные можно вставить прелодр для более приятной визуализации