# Отображение базы данных с помощью Java Script (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, база-данных

Требуется помощь в решении вопроса, касающегося запросов в базу данных и их отображения на html странице. Есть запрос с двумя параметрами :p1 и :p2, эти параметры собираю с 2 value в 2 раскрывающихся html списках. Нужно, что бы при выборе 2 нужных позиций и нажатии на кнопку происходил запрос в БД и сразу же вывод оттуда данных в html форму. Каким способом это лучше сделать?

Пока что удалось только возвращать собранные данные с этих 2-х списков.

```js
$(function () {
  $("form").bind('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $("form").serialize();
    $("#results").text(form);
    var form = $(this),
      serialize = form.serialize();
  });
});
```

Никак не могу разобраться с тем, как передать данные из JS в PHP скрипт и каким образом их там подставлять в в значения :p1 и :p2, да ещё и так, что бы всё это работало асинхронно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону моего ответа, [ajax запрос по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/864684/ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5/864710#864710) .

Вам в data: необходимо будет отправлять ваши данные с формы:

```
data: { 
   'form_data': form
}
```

В php: ловить по ключу **form_data**.

Answer (score 0):

Бро, крч тебе надо создать файл .php в котором будет запрос в бд с нужным query. 2 значения ты возьмешь из $_POST запроса jquery, назначишь в .php файле

```
if($_POST){ 
$table = $_POST['значение_1'];
$mailVariable = $_POST['значение_2'];
а ниже любой запрос в бд с использованием переменных.
```

Также в файле где берешь ети перменные (в .js) пишешь
`$.post( "test.php", { name: "переменная_1", time: "переменная_2" },function(){//выполнить в случае успеха} );`
Понятно? Вроде все так... И еще тебе надо будет работать c JSON файлами и фетчить в том php файле то шо тебе вернется из запроса в бд а потом возвращать в .js файл/html файл где ajax post запрос. Крч много объяснять - погугли Ajax php mysql

Answer (score 0):

Всем большое спасибо за помощь, удалось решить проблему немного по другому.
Если кому то пригодится:

JS:
Здесь я собираю значения с 2-х селектов в html

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  var name1 = $('#name1').val();
  var name2 = $('#name2').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'config.php',
    data: {
      'name1': +name1,
      'name2': +name2
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('Не удалось выполнить запрос');
      //$("#results").text(textStatus);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
      //$("#results1").text(textStatus);
      $('#content').text(data);
    }
  });
});
```

php:
Тут просто возвращаю обратно

```
if(isset($_GET['name1'])) {
    echo $name = $_GET['name1'];
}

if(isset($_GET['name2'])) {
    echo $name = $_GET['name2'];
    exit();
}
```